# getting a list of all descendants of an element in mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, element

suppose I have a mootools Element
and I want to get a list of all it's descendants (not only direct children)...
how can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting all childs using * css Selector:

```
myElement.getElements('*')
```